# WPF C# Binding to TemplateInstance not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I want to bind the Cursor of a Border to a private property of my TemplateInstance.
**XAML:**

```
        <Border Cursor="{Binding ToggleCursor}">
```

**C#:**

```
        private Cursor ToggleCursor {
            get { 
                return IsEnabled ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }
```

I have also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my TemplateClass:

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }
```

And of course I **notify** the framework about the changes:
(Even if I wouldn't do that it should still get the property at least a single time)

```
        IsEnabledChanged += (sender, e) => OnIsEnabledChanged();
```

and

```
        private void OnIsEnabledChanged() {
            OnPropertyChanged("ToggleCursor");
        }
```

And yes, the class implements the interface.
The problem is, that the border never takes the value from the property. 
F.e. if I return a `Cursors.Cross` in the property it still shows the `Cursors.Arrow`.
Any ideas?

**Example:**
[image]

This is some sort of checkbox with animated behaviour and the blue border recieves the curser binding. Problem solved - Forgot to set datacontext -__-

Comment: Are you raising a propertychanged for ToggleCursor when you change IsEnabled

Comment: @pm_2 Yes, see my comment on toadflakz answer

Comment: Are you creating a custom control here, and trying to change the cursor of a `Border` element based on whether that control is enabled or not?

Comment: @NoelWidmer Which base control is your control derived from? There might be a much easier way of doing what you want using a custom control template and a trigger.

Comment: @StevenRands Derives from Control

Comment: @NoelWidmer Okay, then what behaviour is your custom control implementing? Is there some reason why you've implemented a custom control rather than templating an existing control type? (Not saying there's anything wrong with doing that, just trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish).

Comment: @NoelWidmer Probably redundant now that toadflakz has solved your problem, but I've posted an answer that shows an alternate XAML-based approach to illustrate what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToggleCursor` must be a `public` property and you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("ToggleCursor")` whenever the `ToggleCursor` property value changes (which seems to be related to `IsEnabled` property changes).

Typically this will be via the overridden OnPropertyChanged method:

```
private override void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
{
   base.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
   switch (PropertyName)
   {
      case "IsEnabled":
          OnPropertyChanged("ToggleCursor");
          break;
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

OP set the `ToggleCursor` property to `public` and also assigned the `DataContext` for `TemplateInstance` and this solved his issue.

Comment: I also do this: private void OnIsEnabledChanged() {
            OnPropertyChanged("ToggleCursor");
        } but it has no effect (the method subscribes to the event)

Comment: ToggleCursor **must** be `public`.

Comment: You're wrong. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx

Comment: Alright, good Resource! :) - Still not working, gonna read that now

Comment: How are you setting the `DataContext` for the `TemplateInstance` control to the `TemplateClass` object?

Comment: Ouch! Did not set any DataContext. Now it works -_- Thanks! (And only with a public property)

Comment: Good stuff! Please don't forget to mark this as the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you're re-templating an existing control or creating your own, you need a control style and also need to set a control template inside that style.

In the control template you can use a trigger to change things:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type YourCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type YourCustomControl}">
                <Border x:Name="Border">
                    ... other elements, etc ...
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you don't need to create a custom property in your control class to do this.

Comment: Sure thing! But I like to do most things in code, since it is easier to maintain in my opinion. Thanks for the additinal info :)